# GDB to debug called library function

Tags: linux, gdb

I tried to run example code from github f-stack project https://github.com/F-Stack/f-stack/tree/dev/example, here is the full detail  https://github.com/F-Stack/f-stack/issues/419#issuecomment-612131138

here is my the running example:

```
# gdb --args /usr/src/f-stack/example/helloworld --conf /etc/f-stack-vdev.conf --proc-type=primary --proc-id=0


GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
..........
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/src/f-stack/example/helloworld...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/src/f-stack/example/helloworld --conf /etc/f-stack-vdev.conf --proc-type=primary --proc-id=0
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[dpdk]: lcore_mask=1
[dpdk]: channel=4
[dpdk]: promiscuous=1
[dpdk]: numa_on=0
[dpdk]: tx_csum_offoad_skip=0
[dpdk]: tso=0
[dpdk]: vlan_strip=1
[dpdk]: idle_sleep=0
[dpdk]: pkt_tx_delay=100
[dpdk]: port_list=0
[dpdk]: nb_vdev=1
[dpdk]: nb_bond=0
[vdev0]: path=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/dpdkvhostserver0
[vdev0]: queues=1
[vdev0]: queue_size=256
[vdev0]: mac=00:00:00:00:00:01
[vdev0]: cq=0
[vdev0]: enable=1
[freebsd.boot]: hz=100
[freebsd.boot]: fd_reserve=1024
[freebsd.boot]: kern.ipc.maxsockets=262144
[freebsd.boot]: net.inet.tcp.syncache.hashsize=4096
[freebsd.boot]: net.inet.tcp.syncache.bucketlimit=100
[freebsd.boot]: net.inet.tcp.tcbhashsize=65536
[freebsd.boot]: kern.ncallout=262144
[freebsd.boot]: kern.features.inet6=1
[freebsd.boot]: net.inet6.ip6.auto_linklocal=1
[freebsd.boot]: net.inet6.ip6.accept_rtadv=2
[freebsd.boot]: net.inet6.icmp6.rediraccept=1
[freebsd.boot]: net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=0
[freebsd.sysctl]: kern.ipc.somaxconn=32768
[freebsd.sysctl]: kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=16777216
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.link.ether.inet.maxhold=5
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.fast_finwait2_recycle=1
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.sendspace=16384
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.recvspace=8192
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.cc.algorithm=cubic
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_max=16777216
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_max=16777216
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_auto=1
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_auto=1
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_inc=16384
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_inc=524288
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.sack.enable=1
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.blackhole=1
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.msl=2000
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=0
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.ip.redirect=0
[freebsd.sysctl]: net.inet.ip.forwarding=0

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555682de4 in ff_load_config ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555682de4 in ff_load_config () <----------
#1  0x000055555568dd39 in ff_init ()
#2  0x00005555555b5012 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at main.c:112
(gdb)
```

so it appears something went wrong in ff_load_config, and ff_load_config should come from /usr/local/lib/libfstack.a

How do I use GDB to debug into ff_load_config to figure out the segmentation fault?

Comment: The first thing is try, if you're able to, is to rebuild libfstack.a with debugging info. To do that, edit the Makefile in the lib directory to remove the `#` from `#DEBUG=-O0 -gdwarf-2 -g3 -Wno-format-truncation`, do `make clean`, and do the compile and install again. Note that compiling this way may make the program run slower.

Comment: thanks for the comment, yes I did comment out the #DEBUG, still I could not get much debug information out of the function, it could be because my GDB skills are limited, any further tip would be appreciated!

Comment: Oh, you'll need to rebuild your helloworld program, too, to link in the newly built libfstack.a.

Comment: yes, I did rebuild helloworld :) any specific gdb command you think might help?

Comment: Maybe someone else here knows what else to try to get debug info into your helloword program. Otherwise, you're left with assembly-language debugging. Use `disassemble` to show the instructions of ff_load_config, then figure out how they map to the source code. Use `info reg` to show the values of registers, and `x` to examine bytes and words of data.